# Raspberry Pi 3 with Windows 10 IoT will occasionally take hours to reboot

Tags: pi-3, boot-issues, windows-iot

We have multiple Raspberry Pi 3's all running Windows 10 IoT which all have the same software running on it. Occasionally, the software will reboot the device using the [Shutdown Manager .NET API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.shutdownmanager). This usually works fine, however we have seen a few reboots which have taken hours (a recent one from 2 days ago took around 7 hours to reboot).

Looking at the Windows logs on the device, just before the shutdown I see the windows log `The operating system is shutting down at system time <time>` and 7 hours later it has the log `The operating system started at system time <time>`. So there are no Windows logs at all during this reboot. It is also not installing a Windows update during this time. While the Pi is in this rebooting state, we can cause it to restart immediately by turning off and on the power.

We do not have a way to consistently reproduce this issue, and we have never seen it take this long on a first boot. What are some potential causes of this issue?

Specs:

- Pi: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B V1.2
- OS: Windows 10 IoT Core v10.0.17763.107
- SD Card: SanDisk Ultra 16GB microSDHC UHS-1 Card

Comment: My wild guess is that the on board poly fuse gets crazy.  I heard that if a poly fuse is "triggered", it takes a long time, up to a couple of days to "recover".

Comment: Quick update: Microsoft have reproduced it and are investigating https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/328ae719-cbb3-427c-a294-bb9a1e7c3a6b/raspberry-pi-3-with-windows-10-iot-will-occasionally-take-hours-to-reboot?forum=WindowsIoT

Comment: I read your discussion with MicroSoft and found it very interesting.  So my wild guess on polyfuse was wrong.  I hope MicroSoft can find out the weird cause soon.